# credit vs debit in a balance sheet dont add up to initial value

Tags: numerical-methods

here is a very crazy question but i would like to know if the question is misleading me or am i being misled?

```
credit of 100 in hand.
i spent 40 so bal is 60
spent 30 so bal is 30
spent 18 so bal is 12
spent 12 so bal is 0

when i add up my spent amount it totals 100 (initial figure - 40+30+18+12=100) but when i add up the bal amount (60+30+12=102)
```

still scratching my head on how did the `extra` 2 come from?

Comment: There is no reason to think that adding the balances should give the total owed.  Make sure that what you are adding makes sense to add and represents what you intend it to represent.

Comment: Look at the extreme case where you make one hundred payments of one dollar each.  The list of balances will be $99,98,97,96,\dots$  The sum of these is clearly not going to equal $100$

Answer (score 1):

Adding up each balance is kind of a useless figure. Imagine if you took out one dollar at a time, the sum of the balances would be 5050.